# Gatsby Query for specific post using slug

Tags: reactjs, graphql, content-management-system, gatsby, sanity

I'm attempting to query for a specific blog post using the slug - ***so that a specific post is shown depending on the slug***.

I have encountered the following error: `TypeError: Cannot read property 'Title' of null`

This is the logic to the below code:

1. specify slug in my filter
2. then `eq` (equals) the variable `$slug`
3. the above variable will allow me to dynamically filter, instead of manually making a query for every post in the backend
4. I then query the data on the front end with `data.sanityPosts.Title`
5. `Title` is undefined for some reason

```
export const query = graphql` {
sanityPosts(slug: {current: {eq: "$slug"}}) {
    Title
  }
}
`;

const singlePost = ({ data }) => (
    <Layout>
        <Header />
        <div>
        <h1>{data.sanityPosts.Title}</h1>
        </div>
        <Footer />
    </Layout>
)

export default singlePost
```

Why is `Title` undefined? And how can I approach this in a better way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your component should look like:

```
export const query = graphql` {
sanityPosts(slug: {current: {eq: "$slug"}}) {
    Title
  }
}
`;

const SinglePost = ({ data }) => (
    <Layout>
        <Header />
        <div>
        <h1>{data.sanityPosts.Title}</h1>
        </div>
        <Footer />
    </Layout>
)

export default SinglePost
```

Notice the capitalized `S` in `SinglePost`.

Said that, the only way to pass the `$slug` to a template/page component is using the context API, which is basically what you do in the `gatsby-node.js`. There, you should query for all posts and use the createPages API while iterate through them to create dynamic pages. There, you will expose the context for each post, and you can tell Gatsby where this template is located in order to pass data.

The answer lacks of information, but the workaround should look like:

```
const path = require(`path`)
const { createFilePath } = require(`gatsby-source-filesystem`)
exports.onCreateNode = ({ node, getNode, actions }) => {
  const { createNodeField } = actions
  if (node.internal.type === `MarkdownRemark`) {
    const slug = createFilePath({ node, getNode, basePath: `pages` })
    createNodeField({
      node,
      name: `slug`,
      value: slug,
    })
  }
}
exports.createPages = async ({ graphql, actions }) => {
  const { createPage } = actions
  const result = await graphql(`
    query {
      allMarkdownRemark {
        edges {
          node {
            fields {
              slug
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  `)
  result.data.allMarkdownRemark.edges.forEach(({ node }) => {
    createPage({
      path: node.fields.slug,
      component: path.resolve(`./src/templates/blog-post.js`),
      context: {
        // Data passed to context is available
        // in page queries as GraphQL variables.
        slug: node.fields.slug,
      },
    })
  })
}
```

*Note: of course, adapt the markdown approach (`allMarkdownRemark`) for your Sanity one*

Now you can access to the `slug` in your template:

```
import React from "react"
import { graphql } from "gatsby"
import Layout from "../components/layout"

export default function BlogPost({ data }) {
  const post = data.markdownRemark
  return (
    <Layout>
      <div>
        <h1>{post.frontmatter.title}</h1>
        <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: post.html }} />
      </div>
    </Layout>
  )
}
export const query = graphql`
  query($slug: String!) {
    markdownRemark(fields: { slug: { eq: $slug } }) {
      html
      frontmatter {
        title
      }
    }
  }
`
```

*Note: again, replace the markdown approach for your Sanity*

You can follow the full guide at Gatsby's docs: https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/tutorial/part-seven/

Keep also in mind, that you have exposed the GraphQL playground at `localhost:8000/___graphql` to test your queries in order to know-how are the fields named or how the nested structure should look like, that will save you to know how's `title` field named.